# Como transformar esse codigo de C++ em C?

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, n1, c = 0, c1, c2, max, pos, bar[501], arr[250001], j;
    cin >> n >> n1;
    max = pos = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n*n1; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        c = 0;
        for (j = i; j <= n1*n; j += (n))
        {
            c += arr[j];
        }

        if (max <= c)
        {
            max = c;
            pos = i;
        }

    }

    cout << pos << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu sei que cis é scan, o resto sei nem pra onde vai

Comment: O código é quase válido em `c`. O `include` é distinto (só precisa do `<stdio>`), não se usa `namespace`, impressão é com `printf`

Comment: @Sopergunto Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Exceto pelo *stream* este código já é C, mal escrito, mas é. Ele não foi escrito do jeito do C++, ainda que compile.

Troque `cin` por [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) e `cout` por [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Não se esqueça de incluir o `stdio.h` e tirar tudo ligado ao *stream* de entrada e saída.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, n1, arr[250001];
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &n1);
    int max = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n * n1; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = i; j <= n1 * n; j += n) c += arr[j];
        if (max <= c) {
            max = c;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TWDcHo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jedgmhiq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/PrintfScanf.c).

Comment: E remover o `using namespace`

Comment: Que está ligado ao *stream* :)

Answer (score 1):

Basta trocar os cin por scanf, e o cout por printf e remover o using namespace e trocar a biblioteca para stdio.h

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf e scanf

int main()
{
    int n, i, n1, c = 0, c1, c2, max, pos, bar[501], arr[250001], j;
    scanf("%i%i", &n, &n1);
    max = pos = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n*n1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        c = 0;
        for (j = i; j <= n1*n; j += (n))
        {
            c += arr[j];
        }

        if (max <= c)
        {
            max = c;
            pos = i;
        }

    }

    printf("%i", pos);
    return 0;
}
```